# Call to undefined function Cassandra\\Cluster\\cassandra_cluster_new()

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, cassandra, datastax-php-driver

I'm getting this error when I tried to insert data to cassandra using library `datastax php driver`. I'm using REST. Any idea ?

```
curl --data "x=y&a=b" my_api_url



PHP Fatal error: 
Call to undefined function Cassandra\\Cluster\\cassandra_cluster_new() 
in /prejectdir/datastax/php-driver/src/Cassandra/Cluster/Builder.php on line 142
```

Comment: post more code or clear bit more.  cant get idea on this

Comment: how have you managed to install driver? have't you missed c++ driver? Also as much as I knew datastax driver is directly using binary protocol. not REST, not thrift